# Azure Kubernetes Ingress : 502 Bad Gateway while using Path inside ingress configuration

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

I am facing the 502 Bad gateway issue in my Application Gateway.

I am using Azure Kubernetes Service to deploy my cluster which is connected to Ingress Application Gateway.

Configuration Files:

kube-deployment.yml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myApp
  namespace: en02
  labels:
    app: myApp
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myApp
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myApp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myApp
        image: somecr.azurecr.io/myApp:1.0.0.30
        resources:
          limits:
            memory: "64Mi"
            cpu: "100m"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5100
        env:
        - name: ASPNETCORE_HOSTINGSTARTUPASSEMBLIES
          value: "Microsoft.AspNetCore.ApplicationInsights.HostingStartup"
        - name: "ApplicationInsights__ConnectionString"
          value: "myKey"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: en02
  name: myApp
spec:
  selector:
    app: myApp
  ports:
  - port: 30153
    targetPort: 5100
    protocol: TCP
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  namespace: en02
  name: etopia
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
    appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/health-probe-path: "/api/home"
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /myApp/
        backend:
          service:
            name: myApp
            port:
              number: 30153
        pathType: Exact
```

Result of
`kubectl describe ingress -n en02`

```
Name:             ingress
Labels:           <none>
Namespace:        en02
Address:          public-ip
Ingress Class:    <none>
Default backend:  <default>
Rules:
  Host        Path  Backends
  ----        ----  --------
  *
              /myApp/   myApp:30153 (10.0.0.106:5100)
Annotations:  appgw.ingress.kubernetes.io/health-probe-path: /api/home
              kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
Events:       <none>
```

I am getting expected results from `10.0.0.106:5100/api/home` and Application Gateway health status is 200.

No matter what I do, I always get Bad Gateway error, I was able to access a sample app on port 80 (where the ingress path was /) but if I specify anything in ingress path (/cashify/) it always give me bad gateway.

I tried adding readinessProbe to container but it doesn't work (However I am already getting 200 under application gateway health status).

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if below can be worked around.

Please try to update deployment yaml to use ***wild card path*** specification to  access  apis with different paths.

*deployment.yml*

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
....
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: azure/application-gateway
spec:
  rules:
  - host: xxx
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /api/*   #wild card path
        backend:
          serviceName: apiservice
          servicePort: 80
      - backend:
               .....
          servicePort: 80
```

> **Note** from *[MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-backend-health-troubleshooting#backend-health-status-unhealthy)*: If you want Application Gateway to probe on a different protocol, host name, or path and to recognize a
> different status code as Healthy, configure a custom probe and
> associate it with the HTTP settings.

As you said you have defined [readinessProbe](https://azure.github.io/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/features/probes/) , please ***check if path of those probes is correct.***

> Check same with 1. livenessProbe 2. readinessProbe

- Also please note that readinessProbe and livenessProbe are supported when configured with httpGet.

**References:**

1. [bad request - path based routing · kubernetes-ingress · GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/application-gateway-kubernetes-ingress/issues/355)
2. [application-gateway-troubleshooting-502](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-troubleshooting-502)